# incompatible types;byte[] cannot be converted to byte

Tags: java

> (databaseForm.java)
>
> public class databaseForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Creates new form databaseForm
>  */
>
> String  imgPth = null;
> public databaseForm() {
>     initComponents();
> }
>               
>
> private void jLabelCloseMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
>     // TODO add your handling code here:
>     System.exit(0);
>
> }                                        
>
> private void jLabelMinMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
>     // TODO add your handling code here:
>     this.setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
>
> }                                      
>
> private void jButtonBrowseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {        
>
>     // TODO add your handling code here:
>  
>     Myfunc mf = new  Myfunc();
>     imgPth = mf.browseImage(jLabelDataPic);
>     System.out.println(imgPth);
>
> }                                             
>
> private void jButtonAddDataActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {       
>
>     // TODO add your handling code here:
>    
>     String snumber = jTextFieldSNumber.getText();
>     String fname = jTextFieldFName.getText();
>     String lname = jTextFieldLName.getText();
>     String gender = jComboBoxGender.getSelectedItem().toString();
>     String course = jComboBoxCourse.getSelectedItem().toString();
>     String year = jComboBoxYear.getSelectedItem().toString();
>     String section = jComboBoxSection.getSelectedItem().toString();
>     String address = jTextAreaAddress.getText();
> ```

> ```
>     byte[] img = null;
>     try {
>         
>         Path pth = Paths.get(imgPth);
>         img = Files.readAllBytes(pth);
> ```

> ```
>     data d = new data(0, snumber, fname, lname, gender, course, year, section, img, address, 0);
>     
> }
> ```
>
> (data.java)
>
> public class data {
>
> ```
> private int cid;
> private String SNumber;
> private String FName;
> private String LName;
> private String Gender;
> private String Course;
> private String Year;
> private String Section;
> private byte Image;
> private String Address;
> private int uid;
>
> // Alt + Insert
> // to generate constructor & getters & setters
>
> public data() {}
>
>
> public data(int cid, String SNumber, String FName, String LName, String Gender, String Course, String Year, String Section, byte Image,
> ```
>
> String Address, int uid) {
> this.cid = cid;
> this.SNumber = SNumber;
> this.FName = FName;
> this.LName = LName;
> this.Gender = Gender;
> this.Course = Course;
> this.Year = Year;
> this.Section = Section;
> this.Image = Image;
> this.Address = Address;
> this.uid = uid;
> }
>
> ```
> public int getCid() {
>     return cid;
> }
>
> public void setCid(int cid) {
>     this.cid = cid;
> }
>
> public String getSNumber() {
>     return SNumber;
> }
>
> public void setSNumber(String SNumber) {
>     this.SNumber = SNumber;
> }
>
> public String getFName() {
>     return FName;
> }
>
> public void setFName(String FName) {
>     this.FName = FName;
> }
>
> public String getLName() {
>     return LName;
> }
>
> public void setLName(String LName) {
>     this.LName = LName;
> }
>
> public String getGender() {
>     return Gender;
> }
>
> public void setGender(String Gender) {
>     this.Gender = Gender;
> }
>
> public String getCourse() {
>     return Course;
> }
>
> public void setCourse(String Course) {
>     this.Course = Course;
> }
>
> public String getYear() {
>     return Year;
> }
>
> public void setYear(String Year) {
>     this.Year = Year;
> }
>
> public String getSection() {
>     return Section;
> }
>
> public void setSection(String Section) {
>     this.Section = Section;
> }
>
> public byte getImage() {
>     return Image;
> }
>
> public void setImage(byte Image) {
>     this.Image = Image;
> }
>
> public String getAddress() {
>     return Address;
> }
>
> public void setAddress(String Address) {
>     this.Address = Address;
> }
>
> public int getUid() {
>     return uid;
> }
>
> public void setUid(int uid) {
>     this.uid = uid;
> }
>
>
>  }
> ```

Comment: What is this data class

Comment: I fixed the formatting. Please take a moment to create a [mcve] that we can copy/paste and compile ourselves. [Edit] your question to include this. Also include the entire error message and indicate which line of your code causes the error.

Comment: I'd also encourage you to start following Java naming conventions as early as possible - if `data` is a class, it would conventionally be `Data` (or ideally a more specific term, e.g. `CourseData`), for example.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor, 
`public data(int cid, String SNumber, String FName, String LName, String Gender, String Course, String Year, String Section, byte Image,String Address, int uid)` 
 you are expecting `Image` to be of type byte but passing byte array `byte[] img = null;`
Change the parameter type for `Image` attribute in Data class to `byte[]`